# Question regarding isomorphism between quotient of fundamental groups.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I'm trying to solve the following problem that can be found in Kosniowski's a first course in algebraic topology. This problem is under the chapter on Borsuk Ulam theorem problem $20.7$ d.

### Question

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are **path connected** $G$-spaces for which the action of G is properly discontinuous. Let $p:X\to X/G$ and $q:Y\to Y/G$ denote the canonical projections. Suppose also that $\varphi:X\to Y$ is a $G$ equivariant continuous map. Let $\phi: X/G\to Y/G$ denote the map induced by $\varphi$. Prove that the homomorphism:
$$\phi_*: \pi(X/G,p(x_0))\to \pi(Y/G,q\varphi(x_0))$$
induces a isomorphism:
$$\pi(X/G,p(x_0))/p_*(X,x_0)\to \pi(Y/G,q\varphi(x_0))/q_*\pi(Y,\varphi(x_0))$$

### My attempt

I've been trying to solve the problem under the assumption that the paths X,Y are **path connected**, the original problem doesn't give this hypothesis, but I believe it's a mistake.
Given those conditions we would have that $p,q$ are coverings of $X/G,Y/G$ respectively. Then there's a theorem that says that the groups $\pi(X/G,p x_0)/p_*\pi(X,x_0)$ and $G$ are isomorphic. So we would have have that the groups
$$\pi(X/G,p(x_0))/p_*(X,x_0)\cong G\cong \pi(Y/G,q\varphi(x_0))/q_*\pi(Y,\varphi(x_0))$$

And so in fact they are isomorphic, this however doesn't prove that the homomorphism induced by $\phi_*$ is an isomorphism.

Any help on how to solve this problem would be highly appreciated.